# how to make a hybrid mobile app as ipad/iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, appstore-approval, hybrid

I have a hybrid mobile application which I created using html5 and jQueryMobile. I need to make it as an ipad/iphone application. Please note I didn’t develop the application in mac or Xcode. So I need to know the steps I should follow to make it as an iphone/ipad application.

I am not supposed to distributing it in apple store. We are supposed to give the application to our clients only.

So here are my questions.

1) What are the steps I need to follow to get it as an ios application and give it to my clients? [Mine is a hybrid mobile app not native mobile app]

2) a) Is it necessary that I need a mac machine with Xcode? [Because hybrid mobile application doesn’t need that, but I am concerned while deploying/testing it in a device whether I need a mac machine]
 b) Or ios developer program is enough for me? Because I thought I could get the .ipa file through phoneGap build without having a mac machine.

3) In order to give to the client, not distributing it in apple store, do I need iOS Developer Enterprise Program? [From the following link I feel so]

```
 https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/
```

4) If at all I am distributing it in App Store, is there any criteria apple use to accept the application?
    Please help me with proper answer.  I can’t tell to my client any excuse later. So I would rather prefer answer from someone who has experience in this area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) If I were you, I would get XCode, start an iPhone/iPad app, and write some sort of wrapper with a UIWebView (if you are not willing to fully rewrite in Objective C, which may or may not have a cleaner result and may or may not be easier; it depends on what you are porting).

2) To do what I mentioned above, a Mac with XCode is necessary.  However, there are third party programs that can compile iPhone apps, such as Unity, Flash, and PhoneGap.  I have always worked with XCode so I cannot give you much advice on those.

3) Yes, you will need to pay for the developer program.  You can write code and test with the iPhone Simulator that comes with XCode for free, but to put it on any device, you will need to pay.

4) The short version is that as long as it works, is appropriate, is legal, is useful, and is user friendly, then Apple will accept it.  Usually they will only reject if it is a major problem.  If you want to learn more, you can read the [full version](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply..But I am not planning to develop it as a native app . So there I have the doubt that whether I need a mac machine with xcode..Anyone who has experience in creating hybrid app can help me more...

Comment: Hybrid mobile app is a hybrid between HTML5 and mobile. So you have your HTML5 app built but you still have to write a wrapper class in Objective-C that will display it on iphones/ipads using UIWebView, as WolfLink described. To compile in objective-C, Xcode is required which usually means an apple computer or third party program mentioned above. this link demonstrates this wrapping concept for different platforms - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) For distribution you will need an ipa for iphone and ipad built using Xcode or some other platform.

2)
a) You will require mac and Xcode for testing, debugging if not for building the ipa. If your app is using js having XCode and mac helps a lot.
b) Developer program is useful when you want to install and test your app on devices (installing the ipa that you have already created).

3)You will require iOS Developer Program. But its the client that would require the Enterprise programme to register its users devices in the program and distribute the app.
Only if its you who is distributing the app to specific users you will need the Enterprise program.

4) You will require to submit the app for approval to Apple, before making it available in app store. Following is the link for some help on it-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Hope this helps.